# Find commits that only change whitespace

Tags: git

How can I find all the commits in a git branch that have changes that only modify whitespace? I don't care about merge commits.

More generally, what is the best way to find git commits based on aspects of their diff. I know about `git log -S`, but that only works for very simple cases (when you want to find text in a diff).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do

```
branch=<branch you wish to check>
for commit in $(git rev-list --no-merges $branch); do
    if [ -z "$(git diff -b $commit^..$commit)" ]; then
        echo "$commit only modifies whitespace."
    fi
done
```

Comment: It's rather slow, but it seems to work. I would add `--no-merges` to `git rev-list` to not show merge commits.

Comment: You might want to pipe the `git diff` output into e.g. `head -n 1` so that it doesn't just try to compute the full diff. That might speed it up a fraction.

Comment: I was experimenting with `git diff-tree --quiet --ignore-space-change $commit` as the `if`-condition. That's much faster, but also seems to give wrong results for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

`git log -G<regex>` can be used to search for commits whose diffs contain lines that match a regular expression.

Note that this is different than saying `git log -S<regex> --pickaxe-regex` since that will only show commits whose diffs change *the number of occurrences* of the matching string. In other words, the matching string must appear in *either added or removed* lines in a given file, but not both.

In your case, you could do something like:

```
git log -G"^\s+$" --no-merges
```

where `^\s+$` matches any line in the diff that is nothing but whitespace.

The downside is that this will also include commits whose diffs contain *other lines* besides the ones with only whitespace.